# Rewrite http://example.com/test.asp?index=3 to http://example.com/about

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to Rewrite the old urls generated by ISS to a new system we have build (Joomla).

The url's had to be google friendly. What we want to happen:

```
Rewrite http://example.com/test.asp?index=3 to http://example.com/about
```

I've used a few Rewrite's i knew, but they dont work:

```
RewriteRule ^/test.asp?index=3 / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/test.asp?index(.*)3 / [R=301,L
```

What pice of code am i missing/doeing wrong?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `QUERY_STRING` to check query string.

You can use this code in your htaccess (in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index=3$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test\.asp$ /about [R=301,L]
```

Note: put this rule **before** Joomla's rules